# Passing checkbox value to url using powerform docusign

Tags: php, docusignapi, powerform

Can you guys help me how to pass a value for checkbox input field to the url using powerform docusign, it seems like the docusign does not recognize my settings. I can only pass the value of radio input field.

```
$parameter = "&checkbox_field=1&radio_field=1"
```

where value 1 stands for 'selected' and it working on radio input field, and not working on checkbox.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution to it, just replace value 1 to 'x'.

```
$parameter = "&checkbox_field=x&radio_field=x";
```